# Unable to drop image into TinyMCE

Tags: tinymce-5, tinymce-plugins

I am unable to drag an image into TinyMCE 5.7.0, it just makes an error "Dropped file type is not supported". Dragging and dropping into the image upload modal works fine, but into the main window does not. A similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64782955/tinymce-inline-drag-and-drop-image-upload-not-working/64808202#comment117157682_64808202) had an answer that suggested setting block_unsupported_drop to false but all that does is make the image open in another tab.

Here is the contents of the fiddle

```
<script type="text/javascript">
tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea",
    images_upload_url: '/upload/tinymce',
    automatic_uploads: true,
    image_file_types: 'jpeg,jpg,jpe,jfi,jif,jfif,png,gif,bmp,webp',
});
</script>

<form method="post" action="dump.php">
    <textarea name="content"></textarea>
</form>
```

I created a fiddle that shows the problem https://fiddle.tiny.cloud/25haab

I actually found a commit in TinyMCE that says this version fixed the problem but evidently not. Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: did you find any solution or it is the issue with the editor itself?

Comment: As far as I could tell it was a bug in the editor, although I haven't checked recently to see if there is a newer version.

Answer (score 0):

Solve the drag and drop problem:

> `paste_data_images: true`

But then you will have a lot of trouble with the path of the image, try to find out

> `images_upload_handler` or `images_upload_url`

Comment: "Dropped file type is not supported" => Are you in a mobile environment?